# Maximum value of a expression

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Problem: If $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=20$,  then what is $\max(\sqrt{3\alpha+5}+\sqrt{3\beta+5}+\sqrt{3\gamma+5})$?

My attempt: Assume $\alpha \geq \beta \geq \gamma$. Then $\alpha+\beta+\gamma \leq 3\alpha$ so $25 \leq 3\alpha+5$.

Also $\sqrt{3\alpha+5}+\sqrt{3\beta+5}+\sqrt{3\gamma+5}\leq 3\sqrt{3\alpha+5}$

At this point, I don't have idea what to do next. What should I do next?

Am I doing it incorrectly?

Comment: My intuition tells me $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=20/3$ so the max value would be 15. All variables are behaving symmetrically. Not a rigorous proof, but a good guess, I might say.

Comment: Simply solve with help of AM-HM inequality

Comment: Does not exist, of course. Try $\alpha=-3$

Answer (score 3):

Use Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality:
$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^3u_iv_i\right)^2\le \left(\sum_{i=1}^3u_i^2\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^3v_i^2\right)$$
We choose $u_1=\sqrt{3\alpha+5}$ and so on, and $v_i=1$. Then $$\sqrt{3\alpha+5}+\sqrt{3\beta+5}+\sqrt{3\gamma+5}\le\sqrt{(3\alpha+5+3\beta+5+3\gamma+5)3}=15$$
The equality is achieved when all the terms are equal, for $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=20/3$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $u=\sqrt{3\alpha+5}+\sqrt{3\beta+5}+\sqrt{3\gamma+5}$.

Denote:
$$\begin{cases}
3\alpha +5=a^2\\
3\beta+5=b^2\\
3\gamma +5=c^2
\end{cases}$$
Then, the problem becomes:
$$v=a+b+c\to max \ \ s.t.\ \ a^2+b^2+c^2=75$$and:
$$v^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)=75+2(ab+bc+ca)\le \\
75+2(a^2+b^2+c^2)=225,$$
the equality occurs for $a=b=c=5$.

Hence: $v(5,5,5)=15$ or $u(20/3,20/3,20/3)=15$ is max.

Answer (score 2):

$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=20$

$\implies (3 \alpha + 5) + (3 \beta + 5) + (3 \gamma + 5) = 75$

By [AM-QM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities) inequality,

$\cfrac {\sqrt{3 \alpha + 5} + \sqrt{3 \beta + 5} + \sqrt{3 \gamma + 5}}{3} \leq \sqrt{\cfrac{(3 \alpha + 5) + (3 \beta + 5) + (3 \gamma + 5)}{3}}$

leads to $\sqrt{3 \alpha + 5} + \sqrt{3 \beta + 5} + \sqrt{3 \gamma + 5} \leq 15$

Equality occurs at $\alpha = \beta = \gamma = \cfrac{20}{3}$